# Getstream - How to use the ranking method and personalization?

Tags: getstream-io

By using Ranking method how to filter the most liked activity(or posts) in the getstream, and how to use the personalization?

Give some example related about ranking method and personalization

I have tried the examples given in the documentations but i can't understand what is that filtering?

Answer (score 0):

personalization is a different level from ranking. Here's a [description](https://go.getstream.io/knowledge/evaluating-stream/how-do-i-evaluate-personalization) of personalization.

For ranking, take a look at this post to get ideas: https://getstream.io/blog/getting-started-ranked-feeds-getstream-io/